# horizontal scroll ie9 issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have content in a div that I need to be able to scroll horizontally but is not working in IE9 (always IE!!!)

I have googled this issue and it appears to be a problem when `position: relative;` is applied in CSS

The problem is, I need to use this CSS rule make sure everything in this DIV hides when there is overflow (this is due to z-indoex on a jsPlumb plugin I am using)

here is the CSS I have applied to the DIV:

```
#workflowMain
{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 12px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

If I take off position relative, the scroll works fine, but then some elements inside the div appear outside of the div.

Is there a fix for overflow and position relative in IE or a different way to achieve this?

Comment: And you'd rather not use {overflow-x: scroll}?

Comment: that does fix the problem but annoyingly it puts a disabled scroll bar at the bottom of the div and becomes enabled when the overflow kicks in

Answer (score 0):

*Problem*: The problem is, I need to use this CSS rule make sure everything in this DIV hide when there is overflow of content.

*Solution*: Always put width and height, not with `%` instead always use a defined `px` value

```
#workflowMain
{
width: 200px;
height:100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
clear: both;
padding-top: 12px;
overflow: auto;
position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use fix widths, I need to support variable screen resolutions and the panel needs to take a much horizontal space as possible